# Renderer and Material modules can't be found after angular update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I had to update the packages of the project and now it does not work, I get the number of the issues:
1)

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ngx-draggable-widget/components/NgWidgetPlaceholder.d.ts:3:22 - error TS2724: Module '"D:/../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'? 3 import {
>   ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
>
> node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5761:31
>       5761 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
>                                          ~~~~~~~~~
>       'Renderer2' is declared here.

2)

> import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
>                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ src/app/activeorders/activeorders.component.ts:7:36 - error TS2306:
>   File 'D:/../node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a
>   module.

I already tried the number of the installs/updates but nothing helped, googling did not help neither. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

1) `Renderer` was deprecated for a long time and looks like it was deleted, use `Renderer2` instead.

2) Looks like the path of `MatPaginatorModule` was changed to '@angular/material/paginator' according to https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

Comment: I understand that Renderer was deprecated, but I don't use it directly so I don't have a clue of what and where to change. I don't think it's a good idea to go through the installed modules trying to edit them. And with regards to the material design,the given error was just an example, basically it does not like the common path @angular/material so what should I do with it? Should I specify the path for each component? it's stupid. Besides I can't find placeholder component any longer.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately,  updates can be painful. You can try to find which dependency using old `Rendrer` in node_modules folder and try to update it to the newer version. 2.  There's nothing to do https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503